# Scan COLUMN for key set of initials, get value of that ROW, then get CONTENTS of different CELLS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, indexing, vlookup, invoice

I have access to a review sheet, regarding the review of web content articles for blogs. I'm one of the reviewers.

Here's an image of the review sheet (I'm sorry, I haven't been granted access to embed images):

[EXAMPLE REVIEW SHEET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eHgi.png)

I want to produce in invoice based on that review sheet.  Here's the invoice:

[EXAMPLE INVOICE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtHlA.png)

I understand how to create the link between the two separate spreadsheets, but what I need is this:

In the [EXAMPLE REVIEW SHEET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eHgi.png)  I need to look down COLUMN B (INITIALS) for the last instance only of initials 'MF' and make a note of the ROW

Then, I need to scan back up COLUMN B, for 3 more instances of MF, and make a note of the ROWS for all 3 instances.

I now have the last four instances of MF, and the ROWS they appear.

Now in my [EXAMPLE INVOICE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtHlA.png), I want to populate cells B19-22 with the contents of cells Aw Ax Ay and Az from the [EXAMPLE REVIEW SHEET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eHgi.png), where w, x, y and z are the 4 ROW NUMBERS that we got from the original LOOKUP.

Here's the link to the actual sheets (all on one spreadsheet for the examples)
[ACTUAL SHEETS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gPDL_mP2S6xC07OULh6R_YShlTFcfMyQXVSibTkOkHc/edit?usp=sharing)

For some other invoicing requirements, I found this line of code:

```
=index(B:B,max(row(B:B)*(B:B<>"")))
```

Which I  know returns the lowest-positioned non-empty cell in a column. But I don't really understand WHY it returns it, I just know that it does. I'm sure some part of the INDEX function can help to return the values I need, but I don't know how.

I'm guessing that what I'm looking for is beyond the fx input on the spreadsheet, and requires a script to be run. Whereas I can sometimes make sense of some basic programming - and by that I mean ANSI 74 BASIC, which is where my knowledge stops - I can't really program using the script editor.

What I'd LOVE is if someone could help me, and also explain the logic behind the solution. I'll probably need it in layman's terms, but I'd really like to start understanding how to manipulate spreadsheets - so I'm really keen to find out HOW something like the INDEX code works, and what the variables mean.

I've tried to fathom the explanations given by Google but, TBH, their way of explaining seems to require that you understand their solution before they explain it to you. The examples are very hard to relate to the formulae, because the description of the variables is not 'human' enough.

If anyone fancies a stab at my problem, and could take the time to explain the logic behind the solution, please know that I'll be forever thankful!

Regards,

Miles

Answer (score 0):

I think this formula will work for you, but unfortunately it's a bit more sophisticated than would make it easy to understand.  I placed it in P19 on the Invoice tab.

There are a few different ways to solve your problem, but i wouldn't use INDEX() for any of them.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({'EXAMPLE REVIEW SHEET'!A2:B,ROW('EXAMPLE REVIEW SHEET'!A2:B)},"select Col1 where Col2='MF' order by Col3 limit 4"))
```

If you were willing to have a numbering column to the left of the table in the "Review Sheet" it would make all of this much simpler and I could show you how to do it in a way that might make a bit more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering so quickly!

The REVIEW SHEET is maintained by somebody else, but I have editing rights as I need to fill in my review comments. I was planning to keep a linked copy of REVIEW SHEET as a tab in my Work Spreadsheet. If I do this, then there's no problem with adding a numbering column, or any extra columns that you think will help.

Thanks again

Miles